# I looking for the best way to compress a file/string with PHP

Tags: php, performance, compression

They are many options on php.net website for compression:

- Bzip2
- LZF
- Phar
- Rar
- Zip
- Zlib

I am looking for the best option. In other words witch one is the fastes?

Also I am thinking of splitting the file into multiple ones.

I though about reformatting the files into a giant string and then use a PHP script to split the string after a certain amount of characters. But I am not sure this is the fastes way.

To put the file into a string I was thinking of using base64_encode... Is this the best way?

Thanks in advance for any tip and help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compress? Why are you trying to compress it? Why do you want to split it into many files? Why does it need to be fast? Your question gives no details.

Comment: I am building a service where I need to compress large files. The sizes can very, and the content type too.

Comment: It needs to be fast because I don't want my users to wait to long to decompress the file.

Comment: I am asking because I feer I will make the server crash if they are too many request to compress and split files. I don't really care about the time it takes. But I just dom't want to find my self with a server that is dead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you automating this process for a website or something? Unix provides some really great command line tools (`tar`, `split`, `gzip`, etc..) that do exactly everything you're talking about here..

Comment: Thanks that might be what I am looking for. I don't really care if it's run in the background. Thanks I will look into it.

Answer (score 2):

[base64_encode()](http://php.net/base64_encode) will make the string *longer*, not shorter. It was designed to take binary data, and put it into printable 7-bit ASCII.

*UPDATE:* If you're compressing files for users to download, then it's more important that you make smaller files than it is to do it quickly. In my experience, [Bzip2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bzip2.php) in PHP (or the command-line equivalent) generally yields smaller files.

Answer (score 1):

tar + bz2 should be most effective compression AFAIK. 
But it came with a cost on CPU usage while compressing/decompressing (especially with --best argument on bzip2)